# Default dict with a non-trivial default

Tags: python, defaultdict

I want to create a "default dict" that performs a non-trivial operation on the missing key (like a DB lookup, for example).  I've seen some old answers on here, like [Using the key in collections.defaultdict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7963755/using-the-key-in-collections-defaultdict), that recommend subclassing `collections.defaultdict`.

While this makes sense, is there a reason to use `defaultdict` at this point.  Why not simply subclass `dict` and override its `__missing__` method instead?  Does `defaultdict` provide something else that I'd gain by subclassing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

##### What does `defaultdict` add?

According to [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict), the only difference between a `defaultdict` and a built-in `dict` is:

> It overrides one method and adds one writable instance variable.

The *one method* is the [`__missing__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.__missing__) method which is called when a key that is not present is accessed.

And the *one writable instance variable* is the [`default_factory`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict.default_factory) - a callable with no arguments used by `__missing__` to determine the default value to be used with missing keys.

Roughly equivalent to:

```py
def __missing__(self, key):
    if self.default_factory is None:
        raise KeyError(key)
    self[key] = self.default_factory()
    return self[key]
```

#### When to inherit at all?

It is important to make it clear that the only reason you would even need to create a subclass is if your default value for missing keys ***is dependent of the actual key***. If your default factory doesn't need to key - no matter how complicated the logic is, you can just ***use*** `defaultdict` instead of ***inheriting*** from it. If the logic is too much for a `lambda`, you can still of course create a function and use it:

```py
def calc():
    # very long code
    # calculating a static new key
    # (maybe a DB request to fetch the latest record...)
    return new_value

d = defaultdict(calc)
```

If you actually need the key itself for the calculation of the default value, then you need to inherit:

##### When to inherit from `defaultdict`?

The main advantage is if you want to be able to have a dynamic factory (i.e. change the `default_factory` during runtime) this saves you the bother of implementing that yourself (no need to override `__init__`...).

But, note that this means you will have to take in account the existence of this `default_factory` when you override `__missing__`, as can be seen in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44731234/6045800).

##### When to inherit from `dict`

When you don't care about dynamically changing the factory and can be satisfied with a static one throughout the existence of the dict.

In this case you simply override the `__missing__` method and implement the factory with whatever complicated logic you have dependent of the key.

Comment: Right, so I want to do a lookup based on the key.  For example, something like a dict of employee addresses that does a DB lookup if it doesn't already know a given employee's address.  So the lookup would rely on the key, but would be static.  Sounds like I'm safe inheriting from `dict`.  Thanks for the concise answer!

Comment: Yep sounds like simply inheriting dict and overriding `__missing__` will do the job for you. Happy to help. It was an interesting comparison and a fun answer to make

Comment: [The documentation for `defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) claims that `__missing__` is supported "in addition to the standard `dict` operations". And the documentation for `dict` includes text (*"If a subclass of `dict` defines a method `__missing__()` ... If `__missing__()` is not defined, `KeyError` is raised."*) which implies that it is not defined by the base class. So how can it be correct to talk about it as "overriding" a base class function which does not exist?

Comment: @AJM well the way I see it is that the underlying `__getitem__` of `dict` calls `__missing__` when funny enough it is not actually implemented in the base class which then raises a `KeyError`. You can then "override" it so that soemthing else happens. Whether the use of the word "override" is semantically correct or not, the idea is the same - there is a foundation existing to create the behavior of adding a missing key